# MongoModel Class with Typescript and ES6 Proxy

Tags: typescript, model, es6-class

I want to implement MongoModel class in typescript. 
Which is similar to ActiveRecord in php or rails.

```
class Model {
    data: any; 
}
let model = new Model();
```

What I want to accomplish is

Instead of `model.data.name = 'John'`, I would prefer to `model.name = 'John'`. What is even complicated is that field should be flexible(as mongo does).
`model['anything'] = 'can be assigned'` will finally assign in data property. Will be same as `model.data['anything'] = 'can be anything'`.

I have tried defineProperty but it does not handle all setters/getters.
I have tried Proxy but not sure how to wrap Model class proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, I don't know what a "MongoModel" is, nor do I know what `Base`, `collectionName` and `docId` are supposed to be.  So if the following doesn't match up exactly up to your expectations and you can't adapt it, you might want to consider editing your code to constitute a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  But let's see what we can do here.

First, let's rename your `Model` to `InnerModel` which will be used to implement your desired type but won't be exposed as-is to users:

```
class InnerModel<T> {
  constructor(public data: T) {}
  doSave(): boolean {
    console.log("saving");
    return true; // implement me
  }
}
```

Note that I gave it a constructor to hold the data of type `T`.  The goal now is to make a type like `Model<T>` which acts as both a `T` and an `InnerModel<T>`:

```
type Model<T> = T & InnerModel<T>;
```

If you have a `Model<T>` instance, you can directly access all properties of `T`, plus all properties of `InnerModel<T>`.  Note that I'm completely ignoring what happens if `T` has some of the same property names as `InnerModel`.  That would be bad... if `T` is `{data: number, doSave: boolean}` you're going to have a bad time.  So don't do that.

Anyway, the goal here is to make something that actually constructs instances of `Model<T>`.

Please note that the compiler can't really verify that what you do from here on out will be type safe, so you will need to use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) or the equivalent to prevent the compiler from issuing errors.  That means you have to be careful that you're asserting only something you can verify as true yourself.

First we will add a helper [type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) to help distinguish if a property name is a known key of an object... we will use this next to help the compiler understand whether the property key is on the `InnerModel` itself or on the nested `data` property:

```
function hasKey<T extends object>(obj: T, k: keyof any): k is keyof T {
  return k in obj;
}
```

Here is the main part of the implementation... use a Proxy to route property gets/sets to either the model or the data, depending on where the key is found

```
function makeModel<T>(data: T): Model<T> {
  return new Proxy(new InnerModel(data), {
    get(model: InnerModel<T>, prop: keyof Model<T>) {
      return hasKey(model, prop) ? model[prop] : model.data[prop];
    },
    set(model: InnerModel<T>, prop: keyof Model<T>, value: any) {
      return hasKey(model, prop)
        ? (model[prop] = value)
        : (model.data[prop] = value);
    }
  }) as Model<T>;
}
```

There are a few places where this is not type safe... the `get()` and `set()` handlers return `any`, and `value` is typed as `any` in the `set()` handler. That mostly turns off type checking, so we need to manually check correctness.  And the compiler can't see that we are returning a `Model<T>` as opposed to an `InnerModel<T>`, so we need to assert that.

Finally we will take that `makeModel()` function and treat it as a constructor function.  In JavaScript you can use any function as a [constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new#Description), and if that function returns a value, the constructed object will be that return value.  The compiler really doesn't like us doing that so will need a double assertion:

```
const Model = makeModel as unknown as new <T>(data: T) => Model<T>;
```

But now we have something that works:

```
const n = new Model({
  a: "hey",
  b: 1,
  c: true,
  d() {
    console.log("D");
  }
});

console.log(n.a); // hey
n.a = "you";
console.log(n.a); // you
console.log(n.data.a); // you
n.d(); // D
n.doSave(); // saving
```

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/MYGwhgzhAECSB28CmAnAsgewCZJAHgBUA+aAbwFgAoaaYDeCAFxQFdhGMUAKABxYCMQAS2DQsYRmABc0AgEoyAXyo0sGAMpgAbki5yZ-DBhBIw8Mipq16EY0gB0IDAHMuAIgjah8Z27kBuSxoUJEYWFHNmFiR-aAB6OOghAFseE2SkeEZoDMtlSnyqRgBPHiRoTBx8YmgAXlloADI4RFRK3EIiQMoqADMWeHYhemgAC0gAaSRiwmgkAA9GTKwYDH4AKyR2Ii419ZkCABpoAGsZE+mMXugzYv1TpJgL4quGimpoELCIh+9oPe6hUo-UGjGG5mSYAu7WqO3EkgO9xhnQsHy+4XMyAA7tAAAooDDzYpcbEtZDobC4LjwsByY7vKzQZyhLjJSkgGQIcnI4jHHgEnjnS7XHlEBQMxmfUIYsaTaas9l8gUKAD8OXZAG1+RgeABdaAyNlVew0rUC3XdRmKQ5BaAQFlG3Cc1oUqqdJU6oUvEXs93QLRgEDRGS3cW24LSn7jCBTYmOkAenhycNWNUKqpmnX6+oBoNIZMfSUG6Dp3AmiRgTN6ur+wPRAK2-I0RQKSAVX3EQFUKh0BjZGE11lQpADtsDE7wDBY+CtmCkzrUiuIuokUXdHs2bLmeqkmFcCXSaBuUbTNw2j78GQARnPNGAMiiSFvYj0qMZvdsJkcLncABE-Ja0D5C266UB+djfq48D2LSsQJGM0xUNBYA1m4LwsG43TgV+ThQTBATxIk6EbgwEG4SS5aSPhcFERgLBISaeg0dAv4MWomg6ExhF2l4PhUEAA)

EDIT: if you want it to be "flexible", you should make `T` "flexible" by doing something like `new Model<{[k: string]: any}>({})`, but the more flexible the model, the less strongly-typed it is.  It's up to you if you want to use an [indexable type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) or not, but doesn't really affect the implementation above (or not much anyway)

Comment: Actually, I want to implement somthing like ActiveRecord in php or rails but in typescript (connecting to nosql like mongodb).
And I think your solution makeModel seems to be working. I will try to implement that one and get back to you. Thanks you +1

Comment: Can you please explain me what `const Model = (makeModel as unknown) as new <T>(data: T) => Model<T>;` does? I don't understand that line of code. Thanks.

Comment: https://ibb.co/zrmpKSw Can you check this? I cannot use it as types.
Is there a way I can use it as types?

Comment: It's a generic type, so either you need to specify it (e.g., `const n: Model<{a: string; b: number; c: boolean; d(): void;}> = ...`, or if you have a name `interface Thing {a: string; b: number; c: boolean; d(): void;}>` then you can say `const n: Model<Thing> = ...`), or just let it be inferred as in my example `const n = ... `.